# How to fix flutter project with path issue with :audioplayers_android in Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to run my flutter app in Android Studio, but getting the error:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Project with path ':app' could not be found in project ':audioplayers_android'.

And I, unfortunately, cannot scan this problem because of this issue:

> The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.

Have anyone had any similar experience?
I would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` in your terminal?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, thank you, but outcome is the same: https://imgur.com/a/FGgOwjR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to try updating the version of Gradle in your project. To do this, you can follow these steps:

Open the **build.gradle** file for your project.
Locate the following code in the **buildscript section:**

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

Change the version number to the latest version of Kotlin available, like so:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

Save the file and try running your app again.
If this doesn’t work, you may need to try some other solutions. Here are a few things you can try:

- Make sure that you have the latest version of the **audioplayers** package installed. You can do this by running **flutter packages upgrade** in your project directory.
- Try deleting the **build** directory in your project and rebuilding your app.
- Try running your app on a different device or emulator to see if the issue is specific to your current environment.

I hope this helps!